# Projecting orthogonal matrix onto a low rank subspace gives orthogonal matrix?

Tags: probability, projection, haar-measure

Let $U$ be an $n\times n$ uniformly-random orthogonal matrix, and let $P$ be a projection matrix onto a subspace of rank $k<n$.
Say I take the first $m\ll k$ columns of $U$, denoted as $U_1,\cdots,U_m$, and project it onto $P$.
Will $PU_1,\cdots,PU_m$  be orthogonal with high probability? Can I bind this probability from below?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by a projection matrix?

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes I mean that I project $U_1,\cdots, U_m$ onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is of rank $k$. For simplicity, it can be assumed that I just keep the first $k$ coordinates of each vector and nullify all others.

Comment: I think there are some notational issues in your question. For example, $PU_1,\ldots,PU_m$ (where I think you mean "the matrix made with these vectors") in not a square matrix...

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes I mean that the vectors are mutually orthogonal, that is, that the inner product $<PU_i,PU_j>$ is close to zero whenever $i\neq j$, , $1\leq i,j\leq m$.